# Remote DB connection string failed

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I need to connect the db on another system. while i tried the connection string as

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(192.168.0.125)\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=db_Stock;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
```

error shown:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)"

Comment: If you're connecting to a **remote** SQL Server Express instance, you **must ensure** that this instance **explicitly allows** remote connections - those are **OFF** by default...

Comment: Put IP Address in `Data Source=192.168.0.125`

Comment: Do you have enabled remote access from TCP/IP to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue by following the below site and instructions

link to the site][site](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the brackets

```
Data Source=192.168.0.125\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=db_Stock;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

[ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: removed brackets but the same problem exists

{"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)"}

Comment: Try running the program on the server, does it connect??

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a database user for remote connection, and pass them in your web.config file.

Also you need to set Integrated security=false.
According to [Microsoft][1]

> When **false**, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>   Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.
>
> > **Example:** (192.168.0.125)\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=db_Stock;Integrated Security=True;user id=sa;password=sa123;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

Comment: "You need to create a database user for remote connection" - excuse me? I'd wager that the vast majority of remote connections to SQL Server instances are using windows logins (i.e. remote connections are the norm, and the default settings for SQL Server don't enable SQL logins)